# Write a function pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i) that calculates the minimum number of years left until a loan is fully paid off

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, return

Write a function pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i) that calculates the minimum number of years left until a loan is fully paid off if:

- the amount owned on the loan is currently equal to PV
- the loan is repaid at an amount
- PMT at the END of every YEAR (with the first payment exactly 1 year from now).

  ```
  def pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i):

      year = 1
      n = 1

      while PV > year:
          year = round((PMT * ((1 - (1+i) ** -(n)) / i)),2)
          n += 1
      return int(n)


  pay_off_period(1578934, 15000*12, 0.1045) == 25
  ```

Supposed to be getting 25 but instead I am getting 26. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Probably you should initialize `n` to `0`, not `1`, in order to get the number of loop iterations.

Comment: It still gives the same result as before, even though I did what you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Check the values immediately and only increment the counter if needed.

```
def pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i):
    year = 1
    n = 0
    while True:
        year = round((PMT * ((1 - (1+i) ** -(n)) / i)),2)
        if PV <= year:
            break
        n += 1
    return int(n)
```